# Passing data from fragment to an another

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have an edit text in fragment 1 and a text view in fragment two i want when I change in the edit text the text view in the other fragment changes too

Comment: Please show us what you have tried so far. This is not a coding service so we won't write the whole solution for you. Thanks for understanding.

Comment: @GennadiiSaprykinI'm not searching for the code I just want the method that I have to use  because I tried so many methods using interface and bundle using Sharedprefrence and don't work really thank you

Comment: if you have two fragment which is show one by one, then use Application class for application runtime data save. when edittext value change then it save to application class and when second fragment open, retrieve data from application and set to textview.

Comment: Use listeners to pass on text changed events from edit text to the text view: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextWatcher. Set a listener on the edit text fragment which will be triggered when you type. To get a better answer you need to post your code, because the answer depends on it a lot.

Comment: @ParthSuthar unfortunately this option is not best, because the Application class is too generic. It shouldn't carry such information as edit text strings because it will quickly turn into a mess if used like that. This is a poor design. Application class should only have application scope stuff such as singletons for accessing utilities and global states. Edit text is definitely not a global state.

Answer (score 0):

Use interface to communicate between two fragment. fragment_2 will implement interface and fragment_1 will call that interface method on input change.

FragmentOne

```
class FragmentOne : Fragment() {
    var listener: DataPassCallback? = null

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_one, container, false)
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        et_input.addTextChangedListener(object : TextWatcher {
            override fun afterTextChanged(s: Editable?) {

            }

        override fun beforeTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, count: Int, after: Int) {

        }

            override fun onTextChanged(s: CharSequence, start: Int, before: Int, count: Int) {
                listener?.dataChaged(s.toString())
            }
        })
    }
}
```

FragmentTwo

```
class FragmentTwo : Fragment(), DataPassCallback {

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_two, container, false)
   }

    override fun dataChaged(data: String) {
       td_output.text = data
   }
}
```

Interface to pass data

```
interface DataPassCallback {
    fun dataChaged(data: String)
}
```

The Activity to add those fragment (this is just an example)

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val fragOne = FragmentOne()
        supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction().add(R.id.layout_fragment_one, fragOne).commit()

        val fragTwo = FragmentTwo()
        supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction().add(R.id.layout_fragment_two, fragTwo).commit()

        fragOne.listener = fragTwo
    }
}
```